# pulling a non-trivial object from a MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# .NET 3.5 project using a MySQL database.

I have an object `Task` which I would like to be able to create by pulling it from a series of database tables.

```
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        Values = new List<string>();
        OtherValues = new List<string>();
        Requirement = string.Empty;
        Minimum = 1;
        Children = new List<Foo>();
    }

    public IList<string> Values { get; set; }
    public IList<string> OtherValues { get; set; }
    public string Requirement { get; set; }
    public int Minimum { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }
    public IList<Foo> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to be able to get the tasks from a `TaskList` which would lazily read elements of the task as they were accessed by an enumerator.

```
public class TaskList : IEnumerable<Task>
{
    /* ... */

    public IEnumerator<Task> GetEnumerator()
    {
        string query = @"SELECT my_task.*, `Order` FROM my_task ORDER BY `Order` DESC";
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connection_string_))
        using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                yeild /* ??? */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How is this done?

Comment: Is this the only thing you plan to do with the database? Otherwise I would strongly advise you use an OR/M tool.

Comment: @GertArnold - As you've seen from my other questions, my attempts at OR/M tools have met with failure.

Comment: I don't always read other questions from OPs :). But hey, that's too bad. I knew NHibernate had *some* issues with MySql, but this many!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize it to XML and store it as a string. Add the following function to `Task`:

```
public XElement Serialize()
{
    return new XElement("Task",
            new XElement("Values",from val in Values select new XElement("Item",val)),
            new XElement("OtherValues",from val in OtherValues select new XElement("Item",val)),
            new XElement("Requirement",Requirement),
            new XElement("Minimum",Minimum),
            new XElement("Maximum",Maximum)
            );
}
```

You will need to put `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Xml.Linq;` in the top of the .cs file.

I didn't write the code to serialize `Children` because I don't know what the data type `Foo` looks like, but you should serialize it in a similar manner. After you've done that, you can easily write the XML to the database, and read it back(write a constructor that parses the Xml into a Task object)

**EDIT(addition)**:
Here is an example to a constructors that receives XML(or parse a string as XML):

```
public Task(string xmlSourceAsString):
    this(XElement.Parse(xmlSourceAsString))
{
}
public Task(XElement xmlSource)
{
    Values=(from itm in xmlSource.Element("Values").Elements("Item") select itm.Value).ToList();
    OtherValues=(from itm in xmlSource.Element("OtherValues").Elements("Item") select itm.Value).ToList();
    Requirement=xmlSource.Element("Requirement").Value;
    Minimum=int.Parse(xmlSource.Element("Minimum").Value);
    Maximum=int.Parse(xmlSource.Element("Maximum").Value);
}
```

**EDIT(explanation)**:
You can't store your object as is in the database "as is", because it refers to other objects. For example - the list `Values` doesn't sit in the same place in memory as the rest of the object, befause it's a ref type - it refers to another object that sits in a different place in the memory. In matter of fact, the only parts of your object that are stored in the same place as the main object are the `Minimum` and `Maximum`, which are ref types, so if you could somehow store the object as is(laziest solution possible, if it worked), you would get your Minimum and Maximum fields right, but all other fields will point to the memory addresses where those objects where placed when you stored the Task object, which are now most likely invalid pointers(and I say "most likely" because it is also possible(though rare) that they will point to legitimate objects, maybe event of the same type - but they still won't have *your* data.

If you want the object with all it's data stored in a database(or in a file. or passed to a proccess that runs on another computer via network) you have to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) it. Performance-wise the best way is to serialize it to binary(C# have some tools for that, but it's still more complex than XML).

Xml also have the adventage of being easily readable from most modern programming languages and database engines. [MySQL has some functions to read and write XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html), so you can update the object in the database and access it's fields from MySQL queries.

**Conclusion**
You asked for a solution that is easy(lazy), efficient, and sql-compatible(access to the object's fields from MySQL queries). I say you can only have two of your three requirements, but you can choose which two:

- If you want something easy and efficient, even at the price of loosing compatibility, serialize your objects to binary. True, it's not as easy as XML, but [.NET has some tools to help you with that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx).
- If you want something efficient and compatible, and willing to do some work for that, you can put your object in MySQL the way databases are meant to be used - use separate tables for the lists that refers to the objects via OIDs, etc. This will require some work, but after you add the tables and code the MySQL functions and the C# functions that handle everything, you should be able to store, retrieve, and access your objects with ease.
- If you want something easy and compatible, and you can afford loosing some efficiency, use my solution and serialize your objects to XML. This *is* the laziest solution - unless someone knows a library that can automatically serialize any object, LINQ to XML is the easiest way to do it, and requires much less code than any other solution.

Comment: You mean put the entire object in to a single string-type column in the database encoded as XML? I'd prefer not to do that. 1. because I'd like to lazy-load elements as they're necessary. 2. because  pulling in all that extra XML would be non-performant. 3. because I would lose all database optimizations like ORDER and SELECT WHERE.

Comment: This *is* the lazy solution. The explanation for this is quite long, so I added it to the answer.